# How to run a command in CMD that will run on all AWS ec2 instances I have created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cmd

I was wondering, is it possible and how to run a command from local PC which will then be ran on every ec2 instance I have created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run common administrative tasks on multiple EC2 instances using [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html). Note there are some [pre-requisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-prereqs.html) for using this.